# Error: PDOException - Caused by creating Organic Group within Drupal/Cartaro

Tags: database

Anyone have a solution for the following error:

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[42601]: Syntax error: 7 ERROR: syntax error at or 
near "." LINE 4: INNER JOIN node n ON n.nid = .nid ^: SELECT COUNT(*) AS
expression FROM {comment} c INNER JOIN {node} n ON n.nid = .nid 
WHERE (c.nid = :db_condition_placeholder_0) ; 
Array ( [:db_condition_placeholder_0] => 320 ) 
in PagerDefault->execute() 
(line 74 of /var/www/html/cartaro/includes/pager.inc).
```

This error was the result of creating an organic group and then creating content for the newly created group.

More information about the stack I am working on:

- Drupal
- postgreSQL (MySql is not used)
- Cartaro
- GeoServer
- Ubuntu
- Apache